# When I hover left/right side of a div how do I display previous/next button (using CSS/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i want to happen is when i hover around the left side of the div, i want to display a previous button only, then when i hover around the right side it will display the next button only. how do i do that using CSS or jQuery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container{
                background-color:black;
                width:400px;
                height:200px;
                z-index:-1;
            }
            #leftbutton, #rightbutton{
                background-color:#0F9;
                width:50px;
                height:50px;
                position:absolute;
                top:75px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #rightbutton{
                left:351px;

            }
            #leftbutton{
                left:13px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="leftbutton">Previous</div>
            <div id="rightbutton">Next</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/twish/NKg24/

thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to wrap the actual buttons in a parent element and hide the buttons but not the parent. When you hover over the parent, you set the button to be visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/NKg24/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftbutton">
        <span>Previous</span>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbutton">
        <span>Next</span>
    </div>
</div>

#leftbutton, #rightbutton{
width:50px;
height:50px;
position:absolute;
top:75px;
text-align:center;
/*display:none*/
}

#leftbutton span, #rightbutton span {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#0F9;
}

#leftbutton:hover span, #rightbutton:hover span {
    display:block;
}
```